# Unwanted Margin Below Image

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a div I want to place below it. (Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/d3Mne/1/)

The problem is that there is a margin between the two. This bottom margin is only present with images. Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set `display: block;` on the image :)