# Remove white padding underneath picture within div

Tags: html, css

On this [website](http://www.posterlion.com) underneath each thumbnail you see a white padding of about 5 pixels. I have however no idea where it comes from. When i investigate through Google Inspect I don't see a padding that might be causing it. How do i remove this white padding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add style to image: display:block;

Answer (score 4):

You can also add this `height` property to `#iri`:

`height: 160px;`

Comment: that would be maximum-height then haha yeah i would have to do that anyway because of ie < 9

Comment: @IAlwaysAcceptAnswer: Yes, you may surely add `max-height` for precautions.

Comment: done! together with maximum-width as well :)

Comment: @IAlwaysAcceptAnswer: Haha..extra-precaution..!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. Set:

```
display: block;
```

For the CSS of the image [as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473857/unwanted-margin-below-image).

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an Issue related to padding or margin. This is the default behavior of anchor tags. As normally anchor tag contains text only and mostly they are underlined so whenever anchor tags are rendered a small space is automatically added at the bottom which is usually for the lowercase letters like "j", "y" and "q".

The space below the baseline is referred to as "descender space" since that's where the descender in lowercase letters are drawn. So this problem comes when anchor tags contains images. You can overcome this issue by adding style to `img { display:block; }`